# Yahoo mail can't get attribute background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);?

Tags: html, css, newsletter

I have sent a newsletter html on a address yahoo (...@yahoo.com)
In newsletter html i using code:

```
<div style="background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); bottom: 0px; padding: 0; margin: 0; left: 0; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 55px;">                                                              
   <a href="">title</a>
</div>
```

I read mail yahoo, result is

```
<div style="background: none repeat scroll 0 0; bottom: 0px; padding: 0; margin: 0; left: 0; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 55px;">                                                                 
    <a href="">title</a>
</div>
```

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

For html email you need to call style declarations uncombined. Use the simple `background-color:#252525;` for example.

You obviously are coming from a web background. You'll find that email coding is like coding for the web in the 90's - what you can do (at least across all email clients) is very limiting. I'd avoid divs in favor of tables, not sure if rgba, scroll, overflow etc work either...